# prestashop : What are criteria behind this message

Tags: prestashop

I have added product from database queries but in front office when I go to product detail page I found this message.

There is 1 error

This product is no longer available.
prestashop version is 1.6.1.6

Comment: which version of prestashop is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use queries to add product rather do it like

```
$product = new Product();
$product->name[Context::getContext()->id_lang] = 'Any thing';
$product->link_rewrite[Context::getContext()->id_lang] = Tools::str2url('Any thing');
$product->description[Context::getContext()->id_lang] = 'Lorem ipsum';
$product->quantity = 5;
$product->active = true;
$product->is_virtual = false;
$product->price  = 10.00;
$product->id_category_default  = (Configuration::get('PS_HOME_CATEGORY'))? (int)Configuration::get('PS_HOME_CATEGORY') :
$product->add();
```